# ContentPipeline at runtime in XNA?

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, xna

Does anyone know of anyway to simulate the ContentPipeline in XNA at run-time?

It is my understand that the XNA Content Pipeline makes use of MSBuild at game compile time, which is obviously not redistributable (and definitionally not at run-time).

But if I have an fxb file, and can read the fxb format directly, is there any way to process the file "inline" at run-time, and just build a model myself rather than calling

```
Model m = Content.Load<Model>("resource name")?
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sample on the app hub site does just that:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2

Its associated with widows forms and xna, but you may glean the run time content processing out of it even if your not using winforms.

Comment: Thanks @Steve H.  I had run into this before and dismissed it because it appears to still require MSBuild to be installed, which still presents issues for distributing the application, no?